# How to send image request in CloudSight API in iOS?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, undefined-symbol, cloudsight

I am submitting static image from bundle but I am getting this error: [image]

Here is my [code](http://dpaste.com/1BE93VF)  Can anyone notice my problem?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link in the CloudSight library/framework.

Comment: i have add cloudsight library and also include header file